# Calculate mode of all column values for the same ID using BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have a Bigquery table with columns `id`, `species`, `genre`, and `level`. There are cases that for the same `id`, `species`, and `genre` my table could have different `level` values in multiple rows.

Finally, I want to have 1 row per `id` with `level` value as `mode` of all the `level` values present in the original table for that `id`.

Example

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '123' id, 'dog' species, 'suspense' genre, 3 level  union all 
  select '124', 'cat', 'love', 4 union all 
  select '123', 'dog', 'suspense', 5 union all
  select '123', 'dog', 'suspense', 5 
)
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
```

Expected Outcome:
Same dataset with one row for each id. For eg. in the above example, for `id` 123 level will be `5` (which occurred the most number of times)

How could I achieve this?

[Update]
The above data is just an example. I have 20 million rows in my actual dataset with more than 4 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '123' id, 'dog' species, 'suspense' genre, 3 level  union all 
  select '124', 'cat', 'love', 4 union all 
  select '123', 'dog', 'suspense', 5 union all
  select '123', 'dog', 'suspense', 5 
)
select id, array_agg(level order by cnt desc limit 1)[offset(0)] as mode
from (
  select id, level, count(level) as cnt
  from `project.dataset.table`
  group by id, level
)
group by id
```